# is this jupyter lab? how to change into jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

[I 2023-12-21 22:14:42.517 ServerApp] Package notebook took 0.0000s to import
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:42.555 ServerApp] Package jupyter_lsp took 0.0366s to import
[W 2023-12-21 22:14:42.555 ServerApp] A `_jupyter_server_extension_points` function was not found in jupyter_lsp. Instead, a `_jupyter_server_extension_paths` function was found and will be used for now. This function name will be deprecated in future releases of Jupyter Server.
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:42.563 ServerApp] Package jupyter_server_fileid took 0.0077s to import
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:42.592 ServerApp] Package jupyter_server_terminals took 0.0278s to import
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:42.719 ServerApp] Package jupyter_server_ydoc took 0.1260s to import
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:42.720 ServerApp] Package jupyterlab took 0.0000s to import
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:42.871 ServerApp] Package nbclassic took 0.0085s to import
[W 2023-12-21 22:14:42.875 ServerApp] A `_jupyter_server_extension_points` function was not found in nbclassic. Instead, a `_jupyter_server_extension_paths` function was found and will be used for now. This function name will be deprecated in future releases of Jupyter Server.
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:42.876 ServerApp] Package notebook_shim took 0.0000s to import
[W 2023-12-21 22:14:42.876 ServerApp] A `_jupyter_server_extension_points` function was not found in notebook_shim. Instead, a `_jupyter_server_extension_paths` function was found and will be used for now. This function name will be deprecated in future releases of Jupyter Server.
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:45.440 ServerApp] Package panel.io.jupyter_server_extension took 2.5625s to import
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:45.441 ServerApp] jupyter_lsp | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:45.455 ServerApp] jupyter_server_fileid | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:45.468 ServerApp] jupyter_server_terminals | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:45.480 ServerApp] jupyter_server_ydoc | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:45.492 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:45.502 ServerApp] nbclassic | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:45.514 ServerApp] notebook | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.104 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.105 ServerApp] panel.io.jupyter_server_extension | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.165 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.172 ServerApp] jupyter_lsp | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.172 FileIdExtension] Configured File ID manager: ArbitraryFileIdManager
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.173 FileIdExtension] ArbitraryFileIdManager : Configured root dir: C:/Users/Thiru
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.173 FileIdExtension] ArbitraryFileIdManager : Configured database path: C:\Users\Thiru\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\file_id_manager.db
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.175 FileIdExtension] ArbitraryFileIdManager : Successfully connected to database file.
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.175 FileIdExtension] ArbitraryFileIdManager : Creating File ID tables and indices with journal_mode = DELETE
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.177 FileIdExtension] Attached event listeners.
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.178 ServerApp] jupyter_server_fileid | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.180 ServerApp] jupyter_server_terminals | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.182 ServerApp] jupyter_server_ydoc | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.190 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\Users\Thiru\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.190 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\Thiru\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.192 LabApp] Extension Manager is 'pypi'.
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.200 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully loaded.

---

| | | |_ __  **| |** *| |* ___
| |*| | '* /  *`/ _` |  */ -*)
_**/| .**/_*,*_*,*|_*___|
|_|

Read the migration plan to Notebook 7 to learn about the new features and the actions to take if you are using extensions.

https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrate_to_notebook7.html

Please note that updating to Notebook 7 might break some of your extensions.

[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.212 ServerApp] nbclassic | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.223 ServerApp] notebook | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.225 ServerApp] panel.io.jupyter_server_extension | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.227 ServerApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.228 ServerApp] The port 8889 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.230 ServerApp] The port 8890 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.231 ServerApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\Thiru
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.232 ServerApp] Jupyter Server 2.10.0 is running at:
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.233 ServerApp] http://localhost:8891/tree?token=5b51df4e57e6cae40a502f3e77653882ef7e59f781b61893
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.236 ServerApp]     http://127.0.0.1:8891/tree?token=5b51df4e57e6cae40a502f3e77653882ef7e59f781b61893
[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.236 ServerApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 2023-12-21 22:14:48.313 ServerApp]

```
To access the server, open this file in a browser:
    file:///C:/Users/Thiru/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-12076-open.html
Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
    http://localhost:8891/tree?token=5b51df4e57e6cae40a502f3e77653882ef7e59f781b61893
    http://127.0.0.1:8891/tree?token=5b51df4e57e6cae40a502f3e77653882ef7e59f781b61893
```

[I 2023-12-21 22:14:48.528 ServerApp] Skipped non-installed server(s): bash-language-server, dockerfile-language-server-nodejs, javascript-typescript-langserver, jedi-language-server, julia-language-server, pyright, python-language-server, r-languageserver, sql-language-server, texlab, typescript-language-server, unified-language-server, vscode-css-languageserver-bin, vscode-html-languageserver-bin, vscode-json-languageserver-bin, yaml-language-server
0.01s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.

Now i open jupyter notebook its opening like lite version anyone can help me

Comment: Your post is unreadable. Is 'what' JupyterLab? Then it goes off the rails as you aren't using code blocks to include your stack trace. Then at the end you say "Now i open jupyter notebook its opening like lite version anyone can help me"? Do you mean JupyterLite? None of what you posted about earlier looks like JupyterLite because it looks like you are running the typical Jupyter on your own local machine given `file:///C:/Users/Thiru/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-12076-open.html`. And so that last sentence isn't at all clear.

Comment: See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) for understanding how to post code blocks. I'd suggest you seek specifically 'fenced code blocks' for what you are trying to do here.